# Multiplayer. Guy shoot at me. Misses. I die?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3

The new call of duty 3 on multiplayer is extremely fun to play, with the new added specialist features,thrust jumping and better balancing of weapons it makes quite the experience to play. I only have one BIG issue:

First thing you should know I play it on the PlayStation 3 version. So, its quite irritating when I shoot at someone (using a weevil) get like 5 or 7 hits and they don't die but a lot of the times when I am being shot at (and this is my main concern) the opponent misses completely, maybe getting one hit on my torso (most of the times using a smg), yet...I die? So does anyone else experience this problem? Is this a glitch or Need I to upgrade my internet speed?

Also note when this problem occurs there are no lagging present.

Comment: Welcome to online multiplayer gaming.

Comment: Sounds like either he's shooting in a vulnerable spot (like the head) or typical online gameplay issues. Knowing Call Of Duty, it's probably the latter. What's your Internet connection bandwidth and ping?

Comment: I also assume that this is on core, as opposed to hardcore, right?

Answer (score 2):

Networks function similarly to this oversimplified scheme:

> **Player A** sends information (bullet) to **Server** then calculates whether it hit or not (based on the next position predicted by the server). **Server** sends information **Player B** that he was hit or not.

What you're experiencing is a game without synchronized shooting, meaning that, you don't need to hit the 'body', but where the body will be. Due to that, you don't need to actually hit people, just try to predict (usually a few pixels in front of them, depending on both of your pings) where he is on HIS computer. With that said, use weapons that shoot a lot of bullets in order to have a higher hit ratio

Comment: Lots of bullets does not necessarily mean a higher hit ratio... More hits overall maybe, but likely more misses too, meaning a likely unchanged ration. Assuming his accuracy doesn't improve.

Comment: I meant hits per clip rather than per bullet. Hit percentage is different because if he's shooting a 'slow' weapon it's much more unlikely that that will hit due to having to lagshoot. That's why 'spraying' is so common in those games. While you may not hit at first, you can spray until you find the hitbox and just go from there